# Loss Development Factors

Tags: optimization, regression, control-theory, linear-regression, actuarial-science

Suppose each quarter, we calculate the change (or factor) from the previous quarter. After a period of time, you will have a list that shows the change from quarter to quarter for however many years. Now, let's say you need to make a prediction: What will next quarters change be in relation to this quarter? Currently, we have three main methods: (1) 4-quarter average, (2) 8-quarter average, (3) all-quarter average.

What would be another, more accurate, approach for determining a development factor?

Comment: There are a gazillion methods for loss reserving. I suggest you start researching some basics and then ask specific questions. Why not google "loss reserving methods" and take it from there? If you are looking for stochastic methods a good starting point may be this freely available [book](https://www.actuaries.ch/fr/downloads/aid!b4ae4834-66cd-464b-bd27-1497194efc96/id!98/Vorlesung_SLR.pdf) by Merz and Wüthrich.

Comment: The three methods I described are the ones we use at the company I work for. I'm not a mathematician, but I'd assume there are practicing Actuaries, or Risk Analysts, on here who have found quick, clean, and accurate selection processes (outside the use of simple averages). I appreciate the textbook recommendation.